# Covering polygon with fixed size squares?

Tags: polygon, geometry, java, algorithm, jts-topology-suite

Can you please advice me of an **algorithm** (which I can implement in a Java) to cover some polygon (not exact cover) with squares of certain size (aXa squares)?

The cover doesn't have to be exact - that is, the cover can be more than the original polygon but the squares can't be intersecting and every square has to have at least one point of intersection with the original polygon.

Comment: Please edit the question to specify the GIS application and version, and the desired data format.

Comment: I'm using the JTS geometry library with Java.

Comment: The algorithm is to cover the area with squares of a certain size.  It's not exactly rocket science, though there is no way (literally, *no way*) to guarantee at least one point of intersection with the original polygon (it's trivial to design a test case to prove this).

Comment: Could you elaborate on that statement, @Vince? It is not clear what you are asserting. After all, one can easily overlay any polygon with *any* regular grid of squares of the desired size, remove every square that has no intersection with the polygon, and be left with a solution to the problem that seems to contradict what you have written.

Comment: Removing squares that don't overlap would be the only way to guarantee overlap, though that's a different problem.

Comment: This JavaBeans script for OpenJUMP may give some inspiration https://groups.google.com/group/openjump-users/attach/381df8eea32b6c83/CreateGrid.bsh?part=0.1 Change "getEnvelopeOfAllLayers" into envelope of your polygon.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of different ways you can do this, and it will vary depending on the software you are using. But in QGIS you can use the Vector Grid tool, which is found in Vector - Research Tools. The tool allows you to set the extent of your working area based on  a layer (in your case the polygon layer) and then output either a line or polygon grid sized at any size you wish (see image below). The result is a continuous grid of square polygons (in this example) that covers the source polygon. If grids are made that do not cover the source polygon, you can just delete them.

[image: Vector Grid Settings]

[image: Vector Grid Output]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm looking for an algorithm rather than a tool

Comment: The beauty of open source is that you can look at the underlaying code, and use it and/or modify it. You should download the plugin and look at the code, there you will see the algorithm you are looking for. Not all answers here are exact or definite, you as the user need to be critical and know what is being provided to you.

Comment: +1 The algorithm is readily apparent from the description.