# Algorithm for breaking polygon into squares

Tags: java, algorithm, jts-topology-suite

We've got some code in our Java application that breaks up polygons into grids for a bunch of reasons. One is to more efficiently spatially index coastal regions (the bounding box tends to cover the entire area of interest and kills performance when querying). The second and more important use case is to support breaking up larger shapes into small regular chunks to support some analysis.

Our current implementation, which is similar to the one suggested as [Speed up Geotools Vector Grid processing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296647/speed-up-geotools-vector-grid-processing), but it's slow as molasses as the grid size gets smaller, not to mention the memory requirements for storing all the cells.  The reason this goes so slowly (for us) is that we're processing thousands of features in this way, all of which can have tens of thousands of points, and we end up doing a ton of intersections for each feature, each of which will be testing the feature's points.

I had an idea for improving the performance and memory requirements of the gridding that takes advantage of the much simpler logic involved in computing an intersection with the axis of the cell, as well as not having to re-compare every point once we know what corner of the quad a point lies in.  I wanted to run the idea past some others to see if this algorithm already exists or not, so I don't have to code it all from scratch if I can avoid it.

The idea is that I recursively break the polygon in to quads around a grid aligned centre point. I can stop recursing once the grid is the desired size, or a grid is completely inside or outside the polygon.

My guts tell me this gives me n log n performance as i can consider fewer points with each recursion, a la merge sort, plus i can group together the contiguous blocks that are inside the polygon to avoid having to store all the coordinates for a grid.

Does this already exist?

Is there an existing implementation somewhere?

I'm finding it hard to search for with my vague description of how it will work. I can see someone was asking this question a while ago as [Covering polygon with fixed size squares?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/128094)

Am I likely to find an optimised algorithm for this in the depths of QGIS?

Note that the reason I want the efficient algorithm is we need a general-purpose fix, and don't want to apply workarounds by preprocessing the data.

*UPDATE* - I've had some great results using this algorithm to break up features in to really small grids, say, 1-5m.  When we release it I'll update the post with a link to the implementation.

Comment: Quadtrees were all the rage in the late 1980s, but never actually panned out. Overlaying a fixed 15 or even 30 degree grid on a global high-resolution country boundaries layer increases feature count by an order of magnitude, but increases point-in-polygon performance by two. You've got a law of diminishing returns working, and are headed in the wrong direction.

Comment: For one of our use cases the whole point of the exercise is to break a large feature up in order to analyze it against something like a raster layer.  For the spatial index use case, we've found the performance increases a lot (I don't have the numbers to hand, but from memory it was significant) when we break up large regional features before putting them in to a kdtree or strtree for spatial look ups.